# Computing the limit $\lim_{n\to \infty} \sqrt[n]{(1+\frac{2}{n})*(1+\frac{4}{n})*(1+\frac{6}{n})*...*(1+\frac{2n}{n})}$

Tags: limits

> $\lim_{n\to \infty} \sqrt[n]{(1+\frac{2}{n})\cdot(1+\frac{4}{n})\cdot(1+\frac{6}{n})\cdot...\cdot(1+\frac{2n}{n})}$ =

$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \left((1+\frac{2}{n})\cdot(1+\frac{4}{n})\cdot(1+\frac{6}{n})\cdot...\cdot(1+\frac{2n}{n})\right)^\frac{1}{n}$$

I would say the result is 1 but I know that is wrong, can someone help me please?

Comment: Try to represent the formula using the factorials, for $n$ even and $n$ odd separately.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

HINT: If we take logarithm of this expression we obtain
$$
\frac1n(\ln(1+2/n)+\ln(1+4/n)+\ldots\ln(1+(2n)/n)).
$$
Can you see a Riemann sum now?

**Edit:** Take $f(x)=\ln(1+2x)$, $x\in[0,1]$. Divide interval $[0,1]$ onto $n$ equal subintervalss and take right hand sides of them. Then
$$
\frac1n\sum_{k=1}^n\ln\left(1+\frac{2k}{n}\right)
$$
is a Riemann sum of 
$$
\int_0^1\ln(1+2x)\,dx.
$$
This integral exists and is easy to compute. From the definition of definite (Riemann) integral it is equal to the limit in question.

Comment: I am a little bit rusty on Riemann, can you please (if you don't mind) guide me on that?

Comment: @Juju9704 Is the extended answer enough?